# Java, Netbeans 8.1 - class wasn't found in project

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Okay, so I am following along with Y. Daniel Liang's *Introduction to Java Programming: (7th) Brief Version*.  The goal is to use five overloaded methods to get a specific type of character randomly.  I am using Netbeans 8.1 as the idea.  The issue I am having is when I try to run the project, I get the error:
"randomcharacter.RandomCharacter class wasn't found in RandomCharacter project".
If I try to run just file, I get: 
class "randomcharacter.RandomCharacter" does not have a main method.

I have already looked around and the only problems I have found are people forgetting their package name, closing braces, and an issue where the file needs to be ran instead of the project.

```
package randomcharacter;

public class RandomCharacter {
  //** Generate a random character between ch1 and ch2 */
  public static char getRandomCharacter(char ch1, char ch2) {
      return (char)(ch1 + Math.random() * (ch2 - ch1 + 1));
  }

 /** Generate a random lowercase letter */
public static char getRandomLowerCaseLetter() {
    return getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');
  }

/** Generate a random uppercase letter */
public static char getRandomUpperCaseLetter() {
    return getRandomCharacter('A', 'Z');
}

/** Generate a random digit character */
public static char getRandomDigitCharacter() {
    return getRandomCharacter('0', '9');
}

/** Generate a random character */
public static char getRandomCharacter() {
    return getRandomCharacter('\u0000', '\uFFFF');
}
}
```

[Here is my screen with the code and the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHYnb.png)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong since I copied the tutorial verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class doesn't have a main method. To run a java program, you need a main method. Without a main method, you can compile and check for errors in the class. Write a main method and implement some tests on the methods you implemented.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char c = getRandomCharacter();
    System.out.println(c);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"randomcharacter.RandomCharacter" does not have a `main` method, it self is the answer. If you want to run java program, you need at least one class with main method. This [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/) might give you some pointers.